AWS Connect start_contact_evaluation not working via Boto3
I tried calling the start_contact_evaluation method of boto3 in Python SDK but it returns an error:
> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the StartContactEvaluation operation: UserId is not a valid identifier
client = boto3.client('connect', region_name='eu-central-1')

response = client.start_contact_evaluation(
InstanceId=instance_id,
ContactId=contact_id,
EvaluationFormId=evaluationf,

I am using aws access key on os env to test the function. It seems that it is an error in the user. I am guessing that the users inside aws connect (not aws users account) are the only ones that are able to start contact evaluation forms.
How can I start a form evaluation programmatically via boto3 ?

Are you adding an agent or manager to answer the contact chat before call start contact evaluation function?

no. I'm not doing that @AlexanderTigselema. On the UI of Connect, I have the possibility to start a contact evaluation but only with my manager's account. However, I want to start a contact evaluation form automatically and answer it using Bedrock without the help of a manager. I don't know how can I achieve that via boto3.
